# Memory leak in Java application

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have an application, that among other things uses SSL. The point of the application is that it will run infinitely. The problem now is, it seems, that over time i get the following image:

[image: Leaking]

Now in the beginning, I take a look at the heap dump (with Memory Analyzer Tool from eclipse) at 2 points: 1 when my app reaches the highest point of memory usage and at the lowest (where, i presume a garbage collection occured.) In the beginning everything is fine, my app has a couple of objects in the finalizer queue and these dissapear. But half hour later, for no apparent reason, while the garbage collection occurs, the references to the finalizer class do not dissapear. These keep increasing in size, and there are 10 references, which point to an object and to the next finalizer in queue, that keep reoccuring. So its actually a repeating chain, of references to the same things, that never gets collected. While this did get collected in the beginning.

So my question is actually 2 fold: first question: What could be the cause of this to suddenly not get collected? (Because I've looked in my code pretty carefully, I'm fairly certain I do close the things that are being referenced by the finalizer class (inputstreams and outputstreams, apparently. Also some abstract stuff from the SSL library i'm using, but fairly certain there is nothing to close there. I'm using a general Client.getConnectionManager().shutdown() which I suppose should clear that up, which it does in the beginning). Could it be, that while the app repeats itself over and over, that for some reason the reference queue got too big and the collector just can't handle it?

Second question is: how might I go about to solving this issue? The image you are seeing is btw from the Jconsole, and when i perform the manual GC, these do all dissapear, and start over.

Any help or nudge in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: `when i perform the manual GC, these do all dissapear, and start over.` Then it is not memory leak, probably GC think that it has enough memory and does not collect objects.

Comment: `Could it be, that while the app repeats itself over and over, that for some reason the reference queue got too big and the collector just can't handle it?` That definitely could happen if objects are added to finalizer queue faster that finalizer thread processes them

Comment: Oh... then what is the up and down going that I am seeing? I was under the impression, that my app allocates memory for the objects, up until 40MB, then gets GC'ed. Is that not the case? I thought there might be a difference between the manual and automatic GC...

Comment: First time GC collects statistics to optimize its work. After it has enough statistics it does not collect all objects, but some of them. It allows to speed up application sacrificing some memory.

Comment: You need to wait longer to see what is happening to heap memory. Just had a look at max memory constraint: `1 851 392 kb`. Gc will not really bother for 20-30 mbytes when it have about 2 GB of free heap

Comment: Try giving you app only 30-40mb and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you have a memory leak at all. What you have is a garbage collector that has not needed to do a full collection. Not to diminish the nature of your program, but it is really quite small, and you have not run it for very long. Certainly not enough to confirm whether there are leaks.

The memory changes you have seen so far are just 'scavenges', and there have not yet been any serious collections yet. Give the GC a chance to do it's job.

Typically the only time any serious collection happens is when there is memory pressure, so expect the more aggressive collections to happen when your various secitons of the heap get full. Right now you are not even close.

Specifically, you have told java it can use about 90MB of memory, and you are currently only using 25MB.... what's the problem?

Comment: I must admit, my knowledge of this is fairly limited. I was just under the impression that GC was allready occuring regularly (everytime the line went down) and that the memory usage was slowly rising to eventually give me the OutOfMemory error. The test is still running, I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If *full GC* clears the situation and moves the bottom memory usage back to the initial 10MB, this means that the *Eden space* / *Survivor space* is to small and/or objects are too early being promoted to *Old generation* (which means they will only be collected when Full GC occures).

I'd suggest starting with the resize of the *Eden space* and *Survivor space*.

Check out [Tuning Garbage Collector documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) and [Java VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for flags like `XX:NewRatio`, `XX:SurvivorRatio` and others that tune up Garbage Collection.

Also read about `XX:InitialTenuringThreshold` and `XX:MaxTenuringThreshold` - those two define thresholds for putting objects into *Old generation*. When used wisely, those two can make your objects stay in *Survivor space* longer, and get collected without *Full GC*.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessarily be memory leak. I do find this fluctuations in the program that runs continuously for months. Once garbage collection occurs, it goes back to normal stage. I'm not sure, but sometimes I have seen that using a profiler makes the fluctuation drastic.